# How can I have the middle column go on top on small screens with Bootstrap 3?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

The following code shows "**1 2 3**":

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        1
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        2
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        3
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I have the main contents on top on smaller screens (phones); "***2* 1 3**"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do this..

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-push-3">
        2
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-md-pull-6">
        1
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        3
    </div>
</div>
```

Demo: http://bootply.com/91812